# Vim - How can I preview markdown as restructured text?

Tags: vim, restructuredtext

## Vim - How can I preview markdown as reStructuredText text?

Hi

I write in markdown and need to *preview as reStructuredText in browser*. My current steps are:

1. Yank markdown in vim
2. Open browser
3. Visit http://pandoc.org/try/
4. Paste markdown
5. Convert to reStructuredText
6. View result in reStructuredText *in browser*
7. Return to vim

Which more elegant solution would you suggest?

Answer (score 2):

[Install pandoc](http://pandoc.org/installing.html) and use the command `pandoc --from=markdown --to=restructuredtext --output=myfile.rst myfile.md` For detailed commands, see the [pandoc manual](http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html).